# Are my forms safe to show to the public?

Tags: php, forms, paypal

Hi I set up a PayPal donation system and I'm using forms with hidden values to make my buttons.  I just thought of the fact that people can view the source and look at these values.  Is there a security threat if they can see something like:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@myemail.com">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Coyote Pack">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="200">  
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="4">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
    <table>
<tr><td>Player Unique ID</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="custom" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online." value="Coyote Pack - $4">   
</form>
```

I guess my question isn't them seeing it, but can they toy with it to give PayPal false values in any way?

For instance, I'm running IPN and my database uses that item_number to give the donator certain privileges.  Can someone just copy my code, paste in their own website, change "amount" to zero and just get the free stuff?

Comment: yes its 'safe',  no information there needs to be secret. you of course check the values via IPN  when payment is made

Comment: Anything sent to the browser can be seen and altered. Assume everything is untrustworthy and work from there.

Comment: Yes, they can change the amount to zero. They can change those values to whatever they like and submit the form to paypal.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this? I guess real paypal button can prevent it?

Comment: you don't prevent it, you check what values paypal returns

Comment: It looks like you need a paypal business account in order to have a secure button. Are you trying to offer some service that people receive if they make a donation?

Comment: And even then, the user can just change the HTML

Answer (score 0):

best solution is this.
In your ipn say:

```
if(preg_match('@^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$@', $itemName) == 1){ // connect to database to retrieve price; }
```

and then say

```
if($priceShouldBe != $pricePaid){ // request was modified and the user did not pay the right price; exit; }
```

and finally say

```
if(preg_match("@^[0-9]+$@", $customVariable) == 1){ /* Check database and then proceed to update database; THIS IS ASSUMING YOU'RE PASSING A NUMERICAL USER ID; Update whatever you need to in the database because the price is right, the name isn't an sqli attempt and the UserId is not an sqli attempt */ }
```